# How can we add existing non supported npm modules to Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am very new to learning VueJS. And I was actually trying to find ways in which we can make non-compliant node modules that are there for different javascript frameworks like React. A good example of this is, [Redoc API tooling](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc). This provides support for React but not for Vue. Now if I want to utilize this in my project in VueJS/NuxtJS based on Vue's component-based approach, how can I do that?

I have tried adding this using '' tag in '' directly as follows,

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <h2 class="title">
      
      </h2>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/redoc/bundles/redoc.standalone.js"> </script>

      <redoc spec-url="./spec.yaml">
        
      </redoc>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  
}
</script>
```

This works. But then I cannot do the necessary customization based on Vue's principles, such as passing the source of OpenAPI documents in 'Props' etc.

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to fly a fighterjet before you've learned to walk: React apps are literally just .js apps that load into an element on your page, so there's nothing stopping you from telling Vue not to manage that single element and having a `<script>` tag that loads your React bundle into wherever it needs to go. However, other than using React for micro-interfaces on a page, why would you use both?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I completely agree with you. I just want to know about right track(documentation) regarding what I am trying to do.

Comment: Except I don't understand what you're trying to do. What does this have to do with `npm`? Why would you need Vue and React-or-any-other-full-framework at the same time?

Comment: So, Vue doesn't support everything in the NPM repository. I have already given an example of one such tool in my question (Redoc), it is not yet supported by Vue. What I want to ask is, what provisions/functionality Vue provides out of the box, (if any?), so that we can support something like Redoc  as component/or something.

Comment: If your question is specifically "how do I use Redoc with Vue", then that's a question for https://github.com/Redocly/redoc/issues, not SO, but if you question is "how do I use anything with Vue", the answer really is "you don't, you use plain JS libraries the same you always have, you don't use tools specifically designed for other frameworks, and for things like redoc you check with the folks that make it, to see if it supports your framework of choice".